# Массив как глобальная переменная

Tags: c#, массивы

Нужно создать глобальный массив visited с длиной StationCount. Пробовал делать его статическим, но при выполнении дальнейших операций выходит ошибка, что индекс вышел за границы массива

```
class Metro
{
    public List<Station> AllStations = new List<Station>();
    public int StationCount { get { return AllStations.Count; } }
    bool[] visited = new bool[StationCount];
    public void AddStation(Station station)
    {
        AllStationss.Add(station);
  }
```

Метод, в котором используется массив visited:

```
public void DFS(int[,] matrix, int curr)
    {
        visited[curr] = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < StationCount; i++)
        {
            if (matrix[curr, i] != 0 && (!visited[i]))
            {
                DFS(matrix, i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: язык-то какой? С++? C#?

Comment: @Сергей язык C#

Comment: проблема не в том, что такая переменная есть, а в том, что ты в массиве указываешь индекс, который больше длины массива......и он не в текущем коде

Comment: @АлексейШиманский но в том коде указываются индексы от 0 до StationCount (если длину visited указать числом что равен StationCount то все работает)

Comment: в каком том? я не вижу кода кроме того, который сейчас в вопросе.........факт фактом - выход за границы - превышение длины в плюс или в минус

Comment: @АлексейШиманский добавил код в пост

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот вы создали список

```
public List<Station> AllStations = new List<Station>();
```

Сколько в нем элементов? 0

Далее создаете массив

```
bool[] visited = new bool[StationCount]; // AllStations.Count
```

То есть массив из 0 элементов.

Далее выполняете

```
visited[curr] = true;
```

Чем бы ни было `curr`, будет исключение, потому что в массиве ничего нет, 0 элементов.

Если вам нужно много `bool` элементов по количеству `Station` в списке, создайте публичное поле в классе `Station` и обращайтесь к нему, массив не нужен вообще.

Comment: Извините, не можете объяснить почему тогда StationCount не пустой, если на момент его инициализации AllStations.Count тоже по сути пустой?

Comment: `StationCount` равен нулю, но ошибка то возникает в строке `visited[curr] = true;`